# Scrape google using proxy with same result

Tags: proxy, web-scraping

Is there any way to scrape google with same total result.

**As here I use proxy to call google.**

But with each time it show me different result due to proxy (geo location of server),

So, Is there any way to scrape google result with proxy servers?

Answer (score 4):

You need to force geolocation using the uule parameter set as country-wide.

Here you can find the theory: http://moz.com/ugc/geolocation-the-ultimate-tip-to-emulate-local-search
And here you can find the script to force-emulate any location: https://github.com/512banque/uule-grabber

FYI uule for USA is: w+CAIQICINVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw
(i.e. query plumber force-geolocated in USA is: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=us&q=plumber&uule=w+CAIQICINVW5pdGVkIFN0YXRlcw )

You can create your custom geo-located query through this tool I put online: http://www.usearchfrom.com

Answer (score 0):

You can also create custom `params` requests using Python `requests` library. Documentation [here](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls).

```
params = {
  "q": "london",                 # <-- search query
  "google_domain": "google.com", # <-- for Germany - google.de and so on.
  "uule": "w+CAIQICIGQnJhemls",  # <-- Brazil
}
```

Code and [full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/RuralIntelligentLevel#main.py) (scraping subtitle from the Google Knowledge Graph):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "london",
  "gl": "br",
  "hl": "pt",
  "uule": "w+CAIQICIGQnJhemls",
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com.br/search', params=params, headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

text = soup.select_one('.E75vKf span').text
print(text)
```

Output:

```
Capital da Inglaterra
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerApi. It solves captchas, rotates proxies, and leverages a full browser cluster. Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=london&location=United%20States&gl=us&hl=en) for more.

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "london",
  "location": "Brazil",
  "google_domain": "google.com.br",
  "gl": "br",
  "hl": "pt",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

subtitle = results['knowledge_graph']['type']
print(subtitle)
```

Output:

```
Capital da Inglaterra
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.